Why doesn't Wolfram Alpha correctly solve $ \sum_{n=1}^{x} n = \prod_{n=1}^{x} n$
$$1 + 2 + 3 = 1 \times 2 \times 3$$
$$ 6 = 6$$
So:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{3} n = \prod_{n=1}^{3} n$$
The problem is that when I put:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{x} n = \prod_{n=1}^{x} n$$
Into WolframAlpha, I get:

For a numerical result of:
$$x ≈ -4.02648640030827...$$
Why don't I just get $x = 3$, especially since the plot obviously has a crossing point there?

$x^2+x=x!$ is still correct. But replacing it with the Gamma function gives another solution, which is not an integer. Of course, your index $x$ should be a positive  integer. So you need to tell this WA, that $x$ is not a real number, but a positive integer.

You can input something like this to get the integral solutions.

What's funny is that it actually draws the desired root correctly.   But, yes, just tell it that you want an integer.

You are looking for $x\in\mathbb{N}$ because that is what makes sense as the upper limit of your summation and your product. However, Wolfram is not solving your initial problem: it is solving $\frac{1}{2}x(x+1)=\Gamma(x+1)$ as an extension for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, which may have other non-integer solutions. Actually, one of them is the numerical solution that it gave you. It could also have given you $x=1$ as a solution, but that depends on the numerical methods that it is using and the initial approximation that it considers.

As a question of why it doesn’t display those solutions in the first prompt, but only displays them when asked for integer solutions, is better suited for a Wolfram forum than this site.

Try solve (sum from n=1 to x of n) = (product from n=1 to x of n) when x>1

@J.W.Tanner: Nice - I did it slightly different than your nice solution (see answer), but reference you since your input is even nicer.

It is sloppy for it to treat $\Gamma(x+1)$ as the same as $x!$ Especially given the original form definitely requires $x$ to be an integer, or the equalities $x(x+1)/2$ and $x!$ is not true. We can only guess why it does this

What happens if you replace x with m in your original question to WA? I am wondering if WA uses conventions.... z= complex, x,y= reals, m,n= integers?

Did people stop caring about the reusability of the questions on this site

Should there be a new tag why-doesn't-closed-source-commercial-software-behave-like-i-think-it-ought-to added?

Try solve (sum from n=1 to x of n) = (product from n=1 to x of n) when x>1
in Wolfram Alpha to get the solution you want.

Because when you implement the equation as
$x!=\Gamma(x+1)=(1/2)x(x+1),$
you don't just get $x=1$ and $x=3$. You intersect the segments of the $\Gamma(x+1)$ function with the parabola representing $(1/2)x(x+1)$ at infinitely many points with negative $x$. Wolfram Alpha's numerical scheme happened to hit one of the negative roots.
We can approximate this root with elementary asymptotic analysis. When $x+4$ is near zero we have $(x+4)!\approx 1$. Dividing out the factor
$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)\approx-6(x+4)$
then gives for $x$ near $-4$:
$x!=\Gamma(x+1)\approx-1/[6(x+4)].$
We also have
$(1/2)x(x+1)\approx6,$
therefore
$-1/[6(x+4)]\approx6\implies x\approx -[4+(1/36)]=-4.027777...$
versus WA's more precise $-4.026486...$.

You can replace $x!$ by the $\Gamma(x+1)$ function and then tell it you want a real answer greater than one (took several tries to figure out a way to coax WA to do it).
The syntax is
  solve 1/2 x (1 + x) == Gamma[1 + x] && x > 1 over reals 

Here is the Wolfram Alpha input.
@J.W.Tanner posted a nice solution that is even closer to your original input.

According to Mathematica, the computation WolframAlpha performed is:
FindRoot[
 (x*(1 + x))/2 - x! == 0, {x, -4.03373, -4.02366}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]

How it chose those two start points, I don't know. With the first two start points $0, 5$, it finds the root $1$, and with start points $2, 5$ it finds the root $3$. None of FindInstance, Reduce, NSolve, or Solve are able to solve the problem as stated without a start point on Mathematica 13.0.1 or 14.0.0. Interestingly the Mathematica statements (e.g. Reduce[x! == (x*(1 + x))/2, {x}, Integers]) that WolframAlpha gives as corresponding to "x! =x(x+1)/2 over the integers" do not actually compute the answers, even though WolframAlpha is displaying the answers correctly.
